# IIS 7 Classic ASP application running in Integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, sitecore, sitecore6

We have a ASP .Net application hosted on IIS 7 on Integrated mode.

We have a few classic ASP pages inside this ASP .Net application. When i am trying to fo form post from classic ASP page and try to access posted data using `Request.Form("name")`, it is giving me unspecified error.  Request object is getting wiped off on form post.

If i change the folder containing classic asp pages to an application and change its application pool to a new application  pool which is using classic mode, everything works fine.

Can i have Classic ASP pages running inside ASP .Net application hosted on IIS 7 in Integrated mode?

We are using Sitecore 6.5 for our web application.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can run ASP Classic on IIS7 using an integrated pipeline.

You might have to add a custom HTTP handler. Take a look at the answer from [Kim Hansen](http://bit.ly/Jw75fT). She uses the following code:

```
<add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" />
```

Take a look at [this](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx) resource for some general tips on running ASP Classic on IIS7.

Some other things to look into:

- 32 bit applications is disabled by default. Some COM objects need this to be enabled. This option can be set per site
- Take a look at the `comPlus` [entry](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/asp/comPlus) in the web.config. Escpecially `executeInMta` can be important in certain cases for Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. We run the app pool in integrated mode and have a custom http module which inspects the request on .net side.
We needed jump over that part in .net code for .asp extenstions and everything worked again.
Seems like whenever .net runs first and accesses the request object it's somehow "locked" for later modules.